# Sort dates which are in different format and select the date which are less than 2 years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below. As you can see the dates are not in same format. I was able to sort it using below query. In addition to this, I also want to add another condition to only get data where the date is less than 2 years from today? How would i achieve that. Any help/direction is appreciated

```
order by (case when saledate like '%/%/%'
               then to_date(saledate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
               else to_date(saledate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          end) DESC OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 2 ROW ONLY;
```

| ID_NUMBER | SALEDATE | SALEAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-07 | 47,000 |
| 2 | 2020-03-25 | 51,470 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | 32,000 |
| 4 | 08/11/2019 | 21,000 |
| 5 | 2018-10-12 | 37,560 |

Comment: I would try to select a subset of this data from the query above. I suggest using the AS statement like this: <Your query here> AS <new table name> and then SELECT * FROM <new table name> WHERE saledate > <some date>.

Comment: You may use `default ... on conversion error` addition of [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) and nest `to_date` with required format instead of`case` expression. What about filter: you may calculate the date in subquery and then select from it with required filter on calculated column

Comment: Your method should work -- but my guess is that you have other bad dates in there too.  You should really spend your effort fixing the data and making the date a `date` rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

A more general method is to use a `case` expression in the format model itself.

As an aside (still related), you may use the `else` clause of `case` to leave the format model `null` for the cases that are not explicitly covered. (`null` is the default value in the `else` clause, so you can leave it out altogether, as I have done below.)

This will result in the "date" strings that are not in one of the explicitly covered formats to become 'null' in the output (instead of throwing an error). Whether that is desirable or not depends on your business use case; anyway, it is demonstrated in the example below.

I am not showing an `order by` (or selecting top two rows, etc.) since that is beside the point; I am just showing how to select strings and show them as dates (but only when the strings are in one of the two explicitly covered formats).

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-Mon-yyyy';
    -- to control the formatting of dates in the output



with
  t (str) as (
    select '2020-01-01' from dual union all
    select '07/13/2021' from dual union all
    select '15.03.2018' from dual union all
    select '20-MAR-18'  from dual union all
    select '11/14/2019' from dual
  )
select str, 
       to_date(str, case when regexp_like(str, '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}')
                         then 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                         when regexp_like(str, '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
                         then 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    end) as dt
from   t;  
 
STR          DT         
----------   -----------
2020-01-01   01-Jan-2020
07/13/2021   13-Jul-2021
15.03.2018            
20-MAR-18             
11/14/2019   14-Nov-2019
```

This may still throw an error - if a string in an explicitly covered format does not represent a valid date.

Note also that I used regular expression comparison - to require that the strings be all digits (other than the punctuation marks used as separators) and to allow one or two digits for month and day-of-the-month, if the use case requires that flexibility.

Of course, you may add more "covered cases" to the format models allowed, by adding them to the `case` expression.